# "INFO me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.CassandraHostRetryService - Downed Host Retry service started with queue size -1 and retry delay 10s" Error

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

```
17 [main] INFO me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.CassandraHostRetryService - Downed Host Retry service started with queue size -1 and retry delay 10s
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/thrift/transport/TTransportException
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.ConcurrentHClientPool.<init>(ConcurrentHClientPool.java:48)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.LeastActiveBalancingPolicy.createConnection(LeastActiveBalancingPolicy.java:59)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.<init>(HConnectionManager.java:65)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.AbstractCluster.<init>(AbstractCluster.java:69)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.AbstractCluster.<init>(AbstractCluster.java:65)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ThriftCluster.<init>(ThriftCluster.java:17)
    at me.prettyprint.hector.api.factory.HFactory.createCluster(HFactory.java:176)
    at me.prettyprint.hector.api.factory.HFactory.getOrCreateCluster(HFactory.java:155)
    at Test.main(Test.java:68)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    ... 9 more
```

I got above error. Please specify what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check if classes is imported or configured correctly in configuration files if you are using some framework.